# Webduino receiving POST params from curl but not from Node

Tags: node.js, http, curl, arduino

Here's the code running on the Arduino, using the [Webduino](https://github.com/sirleech/Webduino) library:

```
void handleConfigRequest(WebServer &server, WebServer::ConnectionType type, char *, bool) {

// POST request to receive new config
if (type == WebServer::POST) {

  bool repeat;
  char name[16], value[50];

  do {
      // Returns false when no more params to read from the input
      repeat = server.readPOSTparam(name, 16, value, 50);

      if (strcmp(name, "dName") == 0) {
        strcpy(deviceName, value);
        Serial.println(value);
      }
  } while (repeat);
}
```

This works as expected (and prints "Test" over serial) when executing the following from curl on the command line:

> curl http://10.0.1.141/config -d "dName=Test"

I have also tested a simple HTML form, which also works and prints "Test" over serial when submitted:

```
<form action="http://10.0.1.141/config">
  <input type="text" name="dName" value="test">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

However, the following Node.js using [request](https://github.com/request/request) code doesn't work:

```
var options = {
    url: "http://10.0.1.141/config",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "User-Agent": "TestingScript"
    },
    form: {dName: "Test"}
  }

  request.post(options, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(error, response, body)
  })
```

Using the Node code, the Arduino acknowledges the HTTP POST request (in this case, by blinking an LED), but does not print "Test" to serial.

I have pointed both curl and my Node code at a requestb.in page, and you can see that the requests themselves appear to be identical (the bottom one is curl, the top is mine):

[image: Requestbin]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is the node version using "https" for the "Cf-visitor" header? Is it possible that the network light is blinking but Webduino is ignoring an HTTPS request?

Comment: I don't see anything in the Node code that would make it HTTPS -- I think it's more to do with how Requestb.in uses SSL internally with Cloudflare

Comment: try forcing User-Agent to "curl/7.51.0"?

Comment: @JoeBeuckman no dice :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I replaced the Node `request` code with the following jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://10.0.1.141/config",
  data: {dName: "Test"}
}, function(data( {
  console.log(data)
}
```

Which worked fine. Odd.